# Not able to get all the id from one function to other

Tags: javascript, html, api

I'm working on OMDB API and I'm making two Request by Search and by ID now I have built the page. but the issue that I'm having is on ID. I created a global variable of movieID and then I gave it the movie ID from API inside a first function and when I'm trying to get those ID's from var movieID, in the second function where I make a new request by ID I only get the last ID of searched MOVIES. I'm a new programmer so please bear with me.

HTML

```
<div id="search-div">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search movie">
</div>

<ul id="movie-showcase">
</ul>

<div class="movie-detail">

</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
const url = 'begining of url by Search';
const apiId = 'apiId';
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const movieDtl = document.querySelector('.movie-detail');
let movieId;

input.addEventListener('keyup', getmovies);

function getmovies(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  if(e.keyCode === 13){
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let inputsearch = input.value;
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
        getdatalist(xhr);
    }
   }
    xhr.open('GET', url + inputsearch + apiId, true);
    xhr.send();
 }
}

function getdatalist(xhr){
    let object = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
    let movieList = object.Search;
    movieList.forEach(function(e){  
        movieId = e.imdbID;
        let list = document.createElement('li');
        let movieDetail = '<img src="'+e.Poster+'" alt="Poster"><h4>'+e.Title+'</h4><button>View More</button>';
        list.innerHTML = movieDetail;
        document.querySelector('ul').appendChild(list);
    }) 
    getdata(movieId);

}

function getdata(movieId){
    let vwbtn = document.querySelectorAll('ul li button');
    vwbtn.forEach(function(elem){
      elem.addEventListener('click', function(){
        getListDetail(movieId);
      })
    })

}


function getListDetail(movieId){
    console.log(movieId);
    const secondurl = 'begining of url by ID';
    const mId = movieId;
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
        let secObject = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
        let detailList = '<div><img src="'+secObject.Poster+'" alt="Poster"><div id="detail-wrap"><div class="layer-1"><h4>'+secObject.Year+'</h4><h4>'+secObject.Released+'</h4><h4>'+secObject.Runtime+'</h4><h4>'+secObject.Genre+'</h4><h4>'+secObject.imdbRating+'</h4></div><h1>'+secObject.Title+'</h1><div class="layer-2"><h4>'+secObject.Production+'</h4><h4>'+secObject.Director+'</h4><h4>'+secObject.Writer+'</h4><h4>'+secObject.Actors+'</h4><h4>'+secObject.Plot+'</h4></div><div class="layer-3"><h4>'+secObject.Language+'</h4><h4>'+secObject.Country+'</h4><button onclick="exitdetail()">Exit</button></div></div></div>';

        movieDtl.innerHTML = detailList;
        movieDtl.style.transform = 'scale(1)';
        }
     }

    xhr.open('GET', secondurl + mId + apiId, true);
    xhr.send();
}


function exitdetail(){
 movieDtl.style.transform = 'scale(0)';

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `let movieId` to `var movieId` or `window.movieId`.

Additionally, if you are storing the id on the global variable you don't have to provide as an argument in the functions. You can access it directly.

Read more about scope [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

Comment: ztadic91 - i  change it in var but in doesn't work -

Comment: Drop the movieId argument in the functions. Access the windows variable directly. var currentMovieId = `window.movieId; window.movieId = e.imdbID`

Answer (score 0):

Function scope - create the variable at the PARENT level to ALL functions that need to access it.

Also, don't forget about the super-easy [localStorage](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/) feature. You really do need to master variable/function scope, but `localStorage` will always be there to save you in a crunch. *(And besides it has other very valid uses over and above bandaid workarounds when struggling with scope.)*